# How can i play a video selected from the sd card?

Tags: android, video, android-activity, sd-card

```
    public class VideoDemo extends Activity {
        private VideoView video;
        private MediaController ctlr;

        File clip=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        {

                if (clip.exists()) {
                video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoGrdView);
                video.setVideoPath(clip.getAbsolutePath());

                ctlr=new MediaController(this);
                ctlr.setMediaPlayer(video);
                video.setMediaController(ctlr);
                video.requestFocus();
                video.start();
        }
   }};
}
```

}

So i've got a VideoGrdView of all videos on my sd card to display in a separate activity, now i need to know how to click a video from the grid and have it play through this media player. Any help is appreciated.

```
    public class Menus extends Activity {
//set constants for MediaStore to query, and show videos
private final static Uri MEDIA_EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI =      
    MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
private final static String _ID = MediaStore.Video.Media._ID;
private final static String MEDIA_DATA = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA;
//flag for which one is used for images selection
private GridView _gallery; 
private Cursor _cursor;
private int _columnIndex;
private int[] _videosId;
private Uri _contentUri;


protected Context _context;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    _context = getApplicationContext();
    _gallery = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.videoGrdVw);
    //set default as external/sdcard uri
    _contentUri = MEDIA_EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    //initialize the videos uri 
    //showToast(_contentUri.getPath());
    initVideosId();
    //set gallery adapter
    setGalleryAdapter();
}
private void setGalleryAdapter() {
    _gallery.setAdapter(new VideoGalleryAdapter(_context));
    _gallery.setOnItemClickListener(_itemClickLis);

}
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener _itemClickLis = new OnItemClickListener() 
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
    {
        // Now we want to actually get the data location of the file
        String [] proj={MEDIA_DATA};
        // We request our cursor again
        _cursor = managedQuery(_contentUri,
                proj, // Which columns to return
                null,       // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
                null,       // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
                null); // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
        // We want to get the column index for the data uri
        int count = _cursor.getCount();
        //
        _cursor.moveToFirst();
        //
        _columnIndex = _cursor.getColumnIndex(MEDIA_DATA);
        // Lets move to the selected item in the cursor
        _cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        startActivity(new Intent("com.ave"));
        }
};
private void initVideosId() {
    try
    {
        //Here we set up a string array of the thumbnail ID column we want to get back
        String [] proj={_ID};
        // Now we create the cursor pointing to the external thumbnail store
        _cursor = managedQuery(_contentUri,
                proj, // Which columns to return
                null,       // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
                null,       // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
                null); // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
        int count= _cursor.getCount();
        // We now get the column index of the thumbnail id
        _columnIndex = _cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID);
        //initialize 
        _videosId = new int[count];
        //move position to first element
        _cursor.moveToFirst();          
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        {           
            int id = _cursor.getInt(_columnIndex);
            //
            _videosId[i]= id;
            //
            _cursor.moveToNext();
            //
        }
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }

}


//
private class VideoGalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    public VideoGalleryAdapter(Context c) 
    {
        _context = c;
    }
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return _videosId.length;
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        ImageView imgVw= new ImageView(_context);;
        try
        {
            if(convertView!=null)
            {
                imgVw= (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            imgVw.setImageBitmap(getImage(_videosId[position]));
            imgVw.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(96, 96));
            imgVw.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("StartActivity:getView()-135: ex " + ex.getClass() +", "+ ex.getMessage());
        }
        return imgVw;
    }

    // Create the thumbnail on the fly
    private Bitmap getImage(int id) {
        Bitmap thumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                getContentResolver(),
                id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
        return thumb;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Do you really want to use your own VideoView? Any specific reason? You could well use the Video player on the device.

Comment: Ok, What problems are you running into? A detailed log would help figure out the problem. I can see that you are not giving the complete file path of the file here.

Comment: Ok, i went ahead and posted more of the code. This code displays thumbnails of all videos on the SD-Card in a videoGridView. And i want to be able to click a thumbnail then have it display in the videoView which would be of course in a new activity. I hope that makes sense. My project is due shortly and i've been stuck for a week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gallery, pretty much works the same way as a ListView. Inside the onItemClick method, you should be able to know which specific item was clicked. Get the Uri/absolute path for that item, and pass on that information to the next activity.

In the VideoDemo class, extract this Uri/path and set it to the VideoView.